# ExtJS: how to submit a multiple-selected combobox's values to the php server in an array, not in the default name-value pairs?

Tags: extjs, combobox, extjs4

The combobox component is in a form panel.

By default, when submit, it will POST as name-value pairs:

```
myName: 'combo-value1',
myName: 'combo-value2'
```

thus the PHP server would only receive the last name-value pair, missing the others.

So I would like the value to be an array:

```
myName: ['combo-value1','combo-value2']
```

so the PHP server won't miss any data.

Comment: Are you submitting data as a list of fields in URL? Or as JSON structure?

Comment: just default, submit a typical POST.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use 'myName[]' for your ExtJS field names instead of 'myName' when multiple values are expected. PHP's parameter parsing requires the square braces suffix on a parameter's name to interpret it as an array value. On the PHP side the value will be available in $_GET or $_POST under the parameter's base name of 'myName'.